# VBA code like maxif

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA challenge, I have spent quite some time trying to solve. I am using the project management template sheet that is to be found on this link:
https://www.vertex42.com/ExcelTemplates/excel-gantt-chart.html

In this I would like to make a function, that finds the minimum and max date of the levels below automatically.

E.g. in row 8 where the WBS is 1, I would like a function in column E that finds the max date of all the rows that start with 1 (e.g. 1.1, 1.2, 1.3)

I have tried this:

```
Function maxIfs(maxRange As Range, criteriaRange As Range, criterion As \Variant) As Variant

maxIfs = Empty
 For i = 1 To maxRange.Cells.count
  If Left(criteriaRange.Cells(i).text, findN(criteriaRange.Cells(i).value)) = Criteria.value Then
    If maxIfs = Empty Then
        maxIfs = maxRange.Cells(i).value
    Else
        maxIfs = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(maxIfs, maxRange.Cells(i).value)
    End If
 End If
Next
End Function

Function findN(text As Variant) As Integer
'Gives the position of the nth delimiter

Dim found As Integer
Dim place As Integer

found = 0
place = 0

For i = 1 To Len(text) + 1 ' Add 1 as we start at 1 not zero
    place = found 'this will be 0 the first time round
    found = InStr(found + 1, text, ".")
Next i

findN = place
End Function
```

I think the issue with the code is, that the WBS column is a function, and therefore there is some issues with the if statement. However, I am not sure if this is true, or how to solve this. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: max startdate? , max enddate? Where is it looking for dates? Column E currently holds start date so are you overwriting this? In which case you might introduce a circular reference. Column E also likely feeds into the gantt formatting.

Comment: Hi QHarr. Thanks for your reply. You are correct, that it may cause some circular references. I am sure that I can fix this with some extra columns. However, I do not think that circular references is the issue here.

Comment: Use the step through mechanism to find exactly where your error is. It is difficult to know what to look for otherwise. Then debug from there.